# Inserting rows on BigQuery: InsertAllRequest Vs BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-dataproc, dataflow

When I'm inserting rows on BigQuery using `writeTableRows`, performance is really bad compared to `InsertAllRequest`. Clearly, something is not setup correctly.

**Use case 1:** I wrote a Java program to process 'sample' Twitter stream using Twitter4j. When a tweet comes in I write it to BigQuery using this:

```
insertAllRequestBuilder.addRow(rowContent);
```

When I run this program from my Mac, it inserts about 1000 rows per minute directly into BigQuery table. I thought I could do better by running a Dataflow job on the cluster.

**Use case 2:** When a tweet comes in, I write it to a topic of Google's PubSub. I run this from my Mac which sends about 1000 messages every minute.

I wrote a **Dataflow** job that reads this topic and writes to BigQuery using `BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()`. I have a 8 machine Dataproc cluster. I started this job on the master node of this cluster with **DataflowRunner**. It's unbelievably slow! Like 100 rows every 5 minutes or so. Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
statuses.apply("ToBQRow", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Status, TableRow>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        Status status = c.element();
        row.set("Id", status.getId());
        row.set("Text", status.getText());
        row.set("RetweetCount", status.getRetweetCount());
        row.set("FavoriteCount", status.getFavoriteCount());
        row.set("Language", status.getLang());
        row.set("ReceivedAt", null);
        row.set("UserId", status.getUser().getId());
        row.set("CountryCode", status.getPlace().getCountryCode());
        row.set("Country", status.getPlace().getCountry());
        c.output(row);
    }
})) 
    .apply("WriteTableRows", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(tweetsTable)//
            .withSchema(schema)
            .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS)
            .withTriggeringFrequency(org.joda.time.Duration.standardMinutes(2))
            .withNumFileShards(1000)
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use a 'SparkRunner'? How do I confirm that it's running on all nodes of my cluster?

Comment: Can you clearify how does Dataproc takes part in your use case. If you are using Dataflow runner this will spin up some GCE VMs(workers) to run the job. Have you tried to change the [parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options) for Cloud Pipeline? You can set more numWorkers and change workerMachineType.

Comment: My bad! DataflowRunner will run on hosted mode. My account doesn't allow me to use more than 4 workers so speed gains are not significant. It's not clear from the documentation exactly which service I need to request quota increase in. If you know, please let me know. I will also keep looking. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should increase the quota of [Compute Engine API CPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#cpus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BigQuery you can either:

- Stream data in. Low latency, up to 100k rows per second, has a cost.
- Batch data in. Way higher latency, incredible throughput, totally free.

That's the difference you are experiencing. If you only want to ingest 1000 rows, batching will be noticeably slower. The same with 10 billion rows will be way faster thru batching, and at no cost.

Dataflow/Bem's `BigQueryIO.writeTableRows` can either stream or batch data in.

With `BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS` the pasted code is choosing batch.

Comment: When I changed it to **BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS**, it's performing better but still overall speed is slow. Interestingly, the "ToBQRow" step is very slow which doesn't make sense 'cause all it does is, create a new TableRow & write it. Is there any way to make that faster?

Comment: Counts from the **ToBQRow**. Input Collections -> Elements added -> 13,829. Output Collections -> Elements Added -> 249. Whoa... this step is **too slow**.